# GIF file creation library with full GIF support

Tags: java, c++, c, image-manipulation, gif

There are many libraries for saving images in [GIF](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp) format, but is there a library with support for GIFs more advanced (or archaic and forgotten if you will) features?

I am thinking about the plain text extension, as well as the ability to redraw only portions of the image for each new frame. The plain text extension could theoretically be used to complement image drawing as well and improve compression of animations, for instance.

I.e. (a)buse the plain text extension to render graphics instead of text. (Most languages would do.)

Comment: You seem to have failed to specify which language you're talking about.

Comment: @Charles, most more or less normal languages would do.

Answer (score 1):

GIFLIB should have everything from GIF

Is this what you mean about plain text?

http://giflib.sourceforge.net/gif_lib.html#idp4823712

Here is the partial frame update

http://giflib.sourceforge.net/gif_lib.html#idp79616

For .NET (full disclosure, I work at Atalasoft) [DotImage Photo Free](http://atalasoft.com/photofree) can do the portion redraw. Look at GifFrame and GifFrameDisposal.  You specify what to do with the previous frame when you draw the new one. Each frame can be any size and positioned, so you can draw only a portion of the image.

Comment: GIFLIB might be exactly what I am after. I will look into how it saves the text, if it uses the built in GIF support for this or if it just writes pixels. Many thanks! DotImage also looks interesting, I might look at it for inspiration.